# Reading each column from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to read each column of a csv file and do some modification before storing them into table.

I have a csv files as :

```
"1";"testOne";"ValueOne"
"2";"testTwo";"ValueTwo"
"3";"testThree";"ValueThree"
```

Here I want to read the first value  "1" and then store it somewhere in a varaible and do something with this value, and similary with the others. However currently I can read the whole file, but could not find the way to access individual columns in a row.

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Python has a built-in [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

Comment: Here print row[0], prints whole row , but i want to print only first column in a row.

Comment: Set the delimeter for this to work reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

Comment: set delimiter at reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';')   It defaults to ',' and you are using ';'

Comment: @ kgiannakakis : the name "row" in "for row in reader" is confusing, maybe it is better to use a different name (such as "element", ...). innit ?

Comment: @DaK, `row` is a row. `row[0]` is the element.

Answer (score 7):

The answer up top is flexible and pythonic, but if you wanted something a bit more compact and slick for retrieving entire columns at a time from delimited data (that fits comfortably into memory), you could also try this:

```
c_reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'r'), delimiter=';')

# say you want the second column, only...
col_2 = list(zip(*c_reader))[1] # keeping in mind that python is 0-indexed

# or if you want to come back for more later on, you can just do...
columns = list(zip(*c_reader))
```

A bit more traditionally pythonic than the former but still functional feeling would be:

```
# just using a good old list comprehension
col_2 = [x[1] for x in c_reader]

# you could also get all the rows simply in this way
rows = [x for x in c_reader]
row_2 = rows[1]
```

Now go forth and be one with the iterables! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) python module:

```
class csv.DictReader(csvfile[, fieldnames=None[, restkey=None[, restval=None[, dialect='excel'[, *args, **kwds]]]]])
```

> Create an object which operates like a regular reader
>   but maps the information read into a
>   dict whose keys are given by the
>   optional fieldnames parameter. If the
>   fieldnames parameter is omitted, the
>   values in the first row of the csvfile
>   will be used as the fieldnames. If the
>   row read has more fields than the
>   fieldnames sequence, the remaining
>   data is added as a sequence keyed by
>   the value of restkey. If the row read
>   has fewer fields than the fieldnames
>   sequence, the remaining keys take the
>   value of the optional restval
>   parameter. Any other optional or
>   keyword arguments are passed to the
>   underlying reader instance.