# Pythonic way to copy a column from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, import-from-csv

I am looking for a pythonic and concise way to select a column in a .csv file and store all cells of the column in, e.g., a list.

```
import csv    

with open("/path/to/file.csv","r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    # TODO: select column for key "foo"
    # TODO: select column for key "bar"
    # TODO:store "foo" data in list
    # TODO: store "bar" data in list
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741518/reading-each-column-from-csv-file

Comment: What, apart from looping over `reader` and just picking out each column by it's column name? `for row in reader: print row['foo']`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Maybe this is already implemented somewhere, along with other tools to manipulate CSV data column-wise.

Comment: Yes, that's what the `csv` module *does*. `DictReader` is a iterable object, and it yields `dict` objects for each row... That's why your question is puzzling.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm sorry, I meant to write *column*-wise

Comment: If you have access to numpy, numpy.loadtxt can save you some time and lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's straightforward to get columns out of DictReader row dicts in pure Python, and someone else is probably writing an answer to that effect right now, so instead of duplicating that effort I'll show how to do this in one of my favourite Python libraries for data manipulation, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("somefile.csv", sep=";")
>>> df
   foo  bar      apple
0    1  100       pear
1    2  200     orange
2    3  300  tangerine
3    4  400      peach
>>> df["foo"]
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: foo
>>> df["bar"]
0    100
1    200
2    300
3    400
Name: bar
>>> df["foo"] * df["bar"]
0     100
1     400
2     900
3    1600
>>> list(df["foo"] * df["bar"])
[100, 400, 900, 1600]
```

In the dark pre-`pandas` days I had my own hand-crafted library for this kind of data access.  After about fifteen minutes with `pandas` a few years ago I tossed it..

Comment: I enjoy Pandas tremendously, but adding yet another dependency is not always the most welcome solution. That being said, if OP intends to do much more data analysis, using Pandas will likely save a lot of pain.

Comment: I intend to do more data analysis indeed, for which I have used R in the past, so Pandas might be the just the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access each column in the file separately, it'd be most efficient to loop over the `csv` *once* collecting the column data:

```
import defaultdict
import csv

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open("/path/to/file.csv","r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        for key, value in row.iteritems():
            defaultdict[key] = value
```

Now `columns` is a dictionary with a list per column:

```
for value in columns['foo']:
    # do something with the `foo` column
# etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-3.2$ cat tcsv.py
import csv
def get_col(filename, col=0):
    for row in csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=';'):
        yield row[col]
print list(get_col("tar.data"))
```

---

```
bash-3.2$ python tcsv.py
['1.0', '4.7', '4.7']
```

---

```
bash-3.2$ cat tar.data
1.0;2.3;4.5;512
4.7;9.2;6.7;240
4.7;1.8;4.3;912
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

def col_selector(table, column_key):
    return [row[column_key] for row in table]

with open("/path/to/file.csv","r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    table = [row for row in reader]
    foo_col = col_selector(table, "foo")
    bar_col = col_selector(table, "bar")
```

This is a straightforward way to do it using a list comprehension in a separate function. Of course, you could get a little bit fancier and make table object with `__getitem__` implemented (like the Pandas answer does), but this seems to work for your purposes.