# spliting text files using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, text

I´m new in reading text files using python. I need to read a file which have in each line 4 data that I need, here is my text file

```
1 -10 0 0    
2 -10 -10 0    
3 0 -10 0    
4 10 -10 0    
5 10 0 0    
6 0 0 0
```

my problem is, that if I use `read().splitlines()`, it only creates a vector with each line, but I need a vector only for the first column, one for the second, one for the third, and also one for the fourth column. Con anyone help me please?

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-with-csv-module) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741518/reading-each-column-from-csv-file).

Comment: do you mean you need a vector for each column?
example [1,2,3,4,5,6] , [-10,-10,0,10,10,0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It open the file for reading as the file pointer `fp`.  It looks at each line, one at a time, removes the newline characters, splits the line into a list on the space character, then converts each element in the list to an integer.  In then forms a list of all of the lists of integers and stores it as the variable `data`.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = [list(map(int, line.strip().split(' '))) for line in fp]
```

Comment: Why? What does it do?

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: James, thanks. That was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

First we make the list of strings that `splitlines` gives us into a list of lists.  Then we can use `zip` to make tuples of those elements that share indices in those lists.

```
list(zip(*map(str.split, f.read().splitlines())))
```

for your input:

```
[('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'), ('-10', '-10', '0', '10', '10', '0'),
 ('0', '-10', '-10', '-10', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')]
```