# Python - Reading Specific column from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to read only first column from csv file. I tried the below code but didn't got the result from available solution.

```
data = open('data.csv')
reader = csv.reader(data)
interestingrows = [i[1] for i in reader]'
```

The error I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "G:/Setups/Python/pnn-3.py", line 12, in <module>
         interestingrows = [i[1] for i in reader]
    File "G:/Setups/Python/pnn-3.py", line 12, in <listcomp>
         interestingrows = [i[1] for i in reader]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `i[1]` will give you the second column not the first. You should try `i[0]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading each column from csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741518/reading-each-column-from-csv-file)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to access columns by their header

For example: If you had a file called "`stackoverflow.csv`" with the headers ("Oopsy", "Daisy", "Rough", and "Tumble")
You could access the first column with this script:

```
import csv
with open(stackoverflow.csv) as csvFile:
#Works if the file is in the same folder, 
# Otherwise include the full path
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row["Oopsy"])
```

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to all this. I've added code, how's it looking?

Comment: Try to be careful with the indentation as it won't work if it is not indented well. (I fix it with edit)

Comment: Useful tip: In question or answer (but not comment), select your code (in text or outside of it) and press `Ctrl+K`

Comment: I just had a try, that makes it so much easier to copy code from notepad onto the site! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first item from an indexable iterable you should use `0` as the index. But in this case you can simply use `zip()` in order to get an iterator of columns and since the `csv.reader` returns an iterator you can use `next()` to get the first column.

```
with open('data.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    first_column  = next(zip(*reader))
```