# Print only second row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium

I have **CSV File** named as *names.csv*:

```
F_Name | L_Name
Sashi  | Thakur
Rup    | Chand
Nirmal | Kumar
```

Trying to print only `L_Name`:

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        #print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
        print(row[1])
```

Gave me:

> KeyError: 2

Thankyou

Comment: you just want to print last names right ?

Comment: @Tanmayjain yes

Comment: @your question title is misleading if you wanted to just print second row remove for loop and do  `next(reader) #skip first row`
 `print(next(reader))#print 2nd row` but clearly this not what you wanted to do

Comment: Please don't use one question to advertise another one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555819/python-reading-specific-column-from-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your latest comment you want to print last name which are in second column(index 1)

If fieldnames are not present then you should not use DictReader as it will take whatever in first row as key

```
import csv
with open('cs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    print(row[1])


#--------------------------------------------------
# fieldnames are present

import csv
with open('cs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    #print(reader.fieldnames) 
    look_for = reader.fieldnames[1] #since L_name is at index 1
    for row in reader:
        print(row[look_for])

'''
csv file contents
F_Name,L_Name
Sherlock,Holmes
Bruce,Wayne

OrderedDict([('F_Name', 'Sherlock'), ('L_Name', 'Holmes')])
Holmes
OrderedDict([('F_Name', 'Bruce'), ('L_Name', 'Wayne')])
Wayne

['F_Name', 'L_Name']
Holmes
Wayne
'''
```

Comment: What if heading is not given?

Comment: @Grass updated the answer if key name is not known but position is

Comment: And what if fieldnames are also not there...?

Comment: @Grass so you want to print second column ?

Comment: I'll be thankfull if you could help me at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121506

Comment: Any updates @TanmayJain with the above question link?

Comment: @Grass I have not work with selenium, so I am sorry can't help you with that question.

Answer (score 0):

Indices start at 0! So to get the the second column you have to access `row[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can user the argument `fieldnames` to give columns key names, then print each column by the key name.

```
import csv with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=['fname', 'lname'])
    for row in reader:
        print(row['lname'])
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html